# jquery children selector doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code

```
$(".cloud").each(function(index, element) {
  var x = (Math.random() * 80) + 1;
  var y = (Math.random() * 80) + 1;
  if (!$(this).attr('id')) {
    $(this).css("top", y + '%');
    $(this).css("left", x + '%');
    $(this).children('a').css("top", y + '%');
    $(this).children('a').css("left", x + '%');
  }
});
```

I was trying to move my cloud picture, the one having .cloud class (and the a href text that's supposed to be on top of it) to a random position. However, the a href text should be on top of the cloud.
So what I was trying to do is, I iterate on each element that has .cloud class, and then tried to set the CSS of its child, too. But I only moved the cloud, not the a href text. What am I missing here?

Here is my markup:

```
<section>
    <div style="height:100%; width: 100%">
        <img src="cloud.png" class="cloud"> <a href="#contact" id="contact" class="cloud">contact</a></img>
        <img src="cloud.png" class="cloud"> <a href="#about" id="about" class="cloud">about</a></img>
        <img src="cloud.png" class="cloud"> <a href="#work" id="work" class="cloud">work</a></img>
        <img src="cloud.png" class="cloud"> </img>
        <img src="cloud.png" class="cloud"> </img>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question. You may need to use `find()` instead of `children()`

Comment: Does the `<a>` element have a `position` property that allows for `top` and `left` values?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I had added the html in question :D

Comment: By the way, `<img>` is a self-closing element, so you should be referencing `<img src="cloud.png" class="cloud" />`...

Comment: @BenM yes, the a href also have .cloud class, which is absolutely positioned.

Comment: Man you have no clue of HTML and writing javascript already? Look at your image tags

Comment: @BenM that's exactly the problem, thank you

Comment: @kidwon yeah, it's for school :/ I always have a difficult time with websites

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`img` elements don't allow to have children - they are "self-closing" tags and you should write them like so:

```
<img src="cloud.png" class="cloud" />
```

then your links are siblings elements, thus you should use `next()` method instead of `children()`

```
$(this).next('a').css({
    "top"  : y + "%",  
    "left" : x + "%"
});
```

As a side note, you may specify an object with all the CSS properties and save some extra calls to the `jQuery` function, so the code becomes

```
var cssprops = {
    "top"  : y + "%",  
    "left" : x + "%"
};

$(this).css(cssprops).next('a').css(cssprops);
```

As a final side note, trying to optimize the code, you may use an unordered list instead of a `div` and wrap every pair "image-link" into a single list-item; then you could assign the css properties only to the `<li>` element

Comment: thank you. that was the problem, I was ignorant about that img element.

Comment: @Rei Make sure you accept the answer with the green tick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
$(this).next('a').css("top", y + '%');
$(this).next('a').css("left", x + '%');
```